# Swift: How to Create Array Holding Dictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm teaching myself swift and am trying to create an array holding dictionaries. The dictionaries are in the following format: String: Any (usually Strings, but sometimes additional arrays of dictionaries).

Is this the correct way to create an array capable of holding dictionaries?

```
var contentArray: [Dictionary<String, Any>] = []
```

Comment: What error? Your code inits an empty array that will only hold Dictionary<String, Any>. If you look at any index, there will be nothing there.

Comment: You could also say something like `var array: [[String : Any]] = []` but either way should work.

Comment: @dylanthelion my mention of the error was unnecessarily confusing and not related to the overall question. I'll remove it. The error came much later, after the array was created and had items appended to it.

Comment: In that case, yes. @Pierce is right about his alternative, and what you have is an empty Array that will only append Dictionaries with that signature.

Comment: you can create an array like var array = [ ["key": "value"],  ["key": "value"] ] directly without declaring a type of array. You can directly store key and value to array.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the question history and saw your edit. `indexOfObjectPassingTest` is a method on `NSArray`. You are asking about `Array` which is a different (though related) type.

Here's how to declare the array:

```
var contentArray = [[String: Any]]()
```

Here's how to get the index of an item:

```
let index1 = contentArray.index(of: aDict)
let index2 = contentArray.index(where: { (some conditions) })
```